# How to change the name of table in SQL Server that is a keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I used `procedure` as the name of a table in SQL Server. And I can't do anything now and get error.

I didn't know it is a reserved keyword.

What should I do ?

Comment: just put it inside `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reserved keywords for table and field names in SQL server when you surround them with square brackets.
So

```
drop table [procedure];
```

should solve the problem. The other option is to find the table dbo.procedure in Object Explorer, right click it, click Delete and choose OK.

Comment: It's better to `Rename` rather than `Drop` the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use brackets `[]` or `QUOTENAME()` with dynamic SQL. But is bad practice at all to use [RESERVED WORDS](https://www.drupal.org/node/141051) as tables, columns names.

Comment: `QUOTENAME(TableName)` will not work with `SQL` like `SELECT * FROM QUOTENAME(PROCEDURE)`. This will only work with dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

You should `Rename` the Table to a non Reserved Keyword which reflects its usage. To Rename the table using something like this.

```
EXEC sp_rename '[procedure]','MyTable','OBJECT'
```

You can continue to use (Not Recommended) the existing name using `[]` in Static SQL like 
`SELECT <ColumnName> FROM [Procedure]`

Or use `QUOTENAME()` where the table name needs to be manually added in case of `Dynamic SQL`. Something like this.

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(10) = 'Procedure'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

you can find the list of Reserved words [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).